# Centering horizontal submenu below parent with css

Tags: css, centering, submenu, alignment

Best shown with a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jnttm/

How can I get the sub-menu to center underneath the parent menu-item?  A lot of the centering tricks I've found don't apply because the child element is wider than the parent.

Is this possible with pure CSS or do I have to resort to javascript?
If JS is required does anyone have JQuery code handy for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you have to define a default `width` to your `submenu` like this :

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    width:300px;
}
.active .sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Jnttm/1/

Comment: the person who give me a downvote please explain me where i am wrong

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but this is exactly what I asked for.  It wouldn't work if there was a background on the sub-menu since it's be wider than the content, but in my case it works.  (Now that I've implemented it though, it doesn't look quite right with the number of sub items, but that wasn't the question :p)

Answer (score 1):

This will center sub menus:

    `ul > ul.sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%)
    }`