# Fix position of horizontal second level HTML menu/list

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

Hello I have a two levels menu like this

```
<ul>
  <li>MenuItem1</li>
  <li>MenuItem2</li>
  <li>MenuItem3
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.1</li>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's a horizontal menu aligned in the center of the page, and what I want to do is when the MenuItem3 is selected its submenu appears, and its item should appear below MenuItem3. What I describe is something like this:

```
MenuItem1   MenuItem2   MenuItem3
                          /\
             SubMenuItem3.1 SubMenuItem3.2
```

I have already done it horizontal and the submenu appears, but the size of the MenuItem3 increases to fit the size of the submenu. So, what I get is something like this:

```
MenuItem1   MenuItem2           MenuItem3
                                   /\
                      SubMenuItem3.1 SubMenuItem3.2
```

Is there any way to fix that? Is that possible with pure CSS?

Thanks!

---

After BenM request, here is the CSS I currently use:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#menu > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#menu > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#menu > ul > li > ul > li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

-------------------------------------
            Edit vol.2
-------------------------------------
After Sen Jacob suggestion I modified a bit this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911298/centering-horizontal-submenu-below-parent-with-css) and because I don't know how many children each top-menu item has, I used Javascript for a proper center alignment. In particular I used the `width()` and `position()` functions of JQuery. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please show us your CSS...

Comment: Updated the original post with the current CSS

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `li` contain the sub`ul`, do this by not closing your `li` early:

```
<li>MenuItem3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.1</li>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.2</li>
    </ul>
```

turns into

```
<li>MenuItem3
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.1</li>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You're right, that's how I have it; I made a mistake on the original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve this?

[CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

Try the following style, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px4tZ/3/)

```
#menu ul {
    width:auto;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 2px;
}
li ul {
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    top:25px;
    right:50%;
}
```

Comment: It's more like the first one you posted (family tree), but I want the position of each parent to be "fixed" regardless their children.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. This is how it appears now. Do you see that the MenuItem3 "moves" on the right side in order to contain its submenu? I want it to remain 2px (as in your CSS) right to the MenuItem2 (like MenuItem2 is 2px right to MenuItem1). In other words I want to move the whole Menu3 to the left. I hope it makes sense. If no, please let me know, and I'll try to upload an image. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly for the last menu item of the top menu. But, what if the submenu was part of the second menu item? For example if we had

`<ul>
  <li>MenuItem1</li>
  <li>MenuItem2
    <ul>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.1</li>
      <li>SubMenuItem3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>MenuItem3</li>
</ul>`

Comment: I found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911298/centering-horizontal-submenu-below-parent-with-css). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I still had problems with the proper center alignment of the children menu items, so I used javascript as well. In particular, I used the JQuery width() and position() functions.