# CSS, How do I center horizontal menu and submenu?

Tags: css

i am learning css and i don't know center a menu and submenu.
i am using margin: auto or margin-left and margin-right to auto but it is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

HTML

```
    <div id="menu">                          
    <ul id="nav">                          
        <li><a href="#">item1</a>            
            <ul>                               
                <li><a href="">subitem1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">subitem2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">subitem3</a></li> 
           </ul>                             
        </li>                                
        <li><a href="#">item2</a>            
            <ul>                               
                <li><a href="">subitem1</a></li> 
              <li><a href="">subitem2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">subitem3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">subitem4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">subitem5</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">subitem6</a></li> 
            </ul>                            
        </li>                                
    </ul>                                  
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {                  
  clear: none;           
  width: 960px;          
}                        
ul#nav {                 
  width: 960px;          
  margin: 0;             
  padding: 0;            
  list-style: none;      
}                        
ul#nav li {              
    float: left;           
    display: inline-block; 
}                        
ul#nav li a {            
  line-height: 40px;     
    padding: 0 30px;       
  text-align: center;    
}                        
ul#nav ul {              
    display: none;         
}                        
ul#nav li:hover > ul {   
  position: absolute;    
    display: block;        
  margin: auto;          
    width: 100%;           
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidgonzalo/ZzaDY

Comment: what kind of center do you want? can you post an image for reference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering horizontal submenu below parent with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911298/centering-horizontal-submenu-below-parent-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Is this your desired outcome?
http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/ZzaDY/1/

(Keep in mind the fiddle window is small so you may have a scrollbar - the content is indeed centered)

1. Add `text-align:center;` to `ul#nav`
2. Get rid of `float: left;` from `ul#nav li`
3. Get rid of `position:absolute;` from `ul#nav li:hover > ul`

### CSS

```
#menu {
  clear: none;
  width: 960px;
}
ul#nav {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:center;
}
ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;  
}
ul#nav li a {
  line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
ul#nav ul {
    display: none;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: when i click on Item1, item2 moves with submenu1 and viceversa, click on item2, item1 moves with submenu2.

Comment: Ah yes I actually just noticed that..... let me work on it some more and come back.

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery? I realize this can be done purely CSS but I had another implementation in mind involving jQuery.  Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ul, li {

 text-align:center;

}


li
{
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

This will center text in menu and sub-menu.