# How do I get my horizontal subnav to center align?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a Horizontal navbar here with Horizontal submenus.  My question is; How do I get the elements in mysubnav to sit centrally and not pushed to the left all the time?

Please see this jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean.

Thanks all for your time with this!  I'm open to all suggestions, be it CSS or JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbkdd7gg/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Occasions</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Valentine's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Easter</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Mother's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Father's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Wedding</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Birthday</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cards &amp; Invitations</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Invitations</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Weddings</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Announcements</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Holiday</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Canvas Prints</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Full Wrap</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Colour Edge Wrap</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Frame</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mugs</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Single Image Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Double Image Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Scrapbook Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Fullwrap Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">14oz Travel Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">17oz Latte Mug</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Device Cases</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Smartphones</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tablets</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">iPods</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photo Gifts</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Keychains</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Mousepads</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Playing Cards</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Puzzles</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
}
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 16.6%;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    text-align: center;
    color:#9a9999;
    height:40px;
}
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#navbar li ul {
    opacity:0;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /*pointer-events:none;*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 1s;
}
#navbar li ul li {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.8em;
    width:14.1%;
}
#navbar li ul li a {
    color:white!important;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top:40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index:-100;
    /*pointer-events:auto;*/
    /*animation: fadein 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.2s;*/
}
#navbar * {
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
    float: left;
    background-color:black;
}
#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
#navbar li li a:hover {
    color: #357;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by elements? text or li's or both?

Comment: The li's themselves. I think I have the text inside the li already aligned to the center.  Do you think that it's possible?  What's throwing me off is the different number if li's under each menu item.  Thanks for having a look!

Comment: so you basically want all the li's in the sub menu grouped together, centrally? equally spacing left and right?

Comment: yes correct.  equal spacing both left and right.  It's probably more simple than I thought.  I could be overthinking it. (I usually do)

Comment: Also feel free to point out anything else that could be corrected or coded a little better. Please be as critical as possible.  :)  Thanks so much for looking at this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at "[CSS, How do I center horizontal menu and submenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174762/css-how-do-i-center-horizontal-menu-and-submenu)"

Shaun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174893) is pretty good. Check out his jsfiddle.